# Eclipse Shortcuts Stopped Working

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, adt, eclipse-adt

After trying to make the ADT plugin work, all shortcuts except `ctrl+c` have stopped working. I went on an updating spree, and might have messed something up. I am on Eclipse Luna. If anyone could help that would be great, I really need shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Eclipse and updated to Eclipse Neon and now it works. I still have the old folder incase anyone wants to try it out to see what's wrong.